# setPosition on a single marker triggers setContent for all markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In one of the applications I'm working on, based on the last known speed of a vehicle, I'm interpolating the next position of the vehicle every 100 ms and plotting it on the map. This is causing a performance issue on mobile devices.

We're also using MarkerWithLabels to put a label next to the Marker

While running the performance profiler, I noticed that `setContent` inside MarkerWithLabels was executing a lot of times and was causing large layout redraws.

[image: Performance Tab]

---

[image: Source Tab]

Putting a `console.log` revealed that it was being called for all the markers that we had even though we were only changing the position of only one of them.

I reproduced this issue in a Codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZwGGr?editors=0011

Short piece of relevant code,

```
var i = 0.002;
setInterval(function() {
    dynamicMarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91627341958452 + i, 151.23648314155578 +i));
    i = i + 0.001;
    console.log('----------**----------');
}, 3000);
```

Marker creation,

```
 var tempMarker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: positions[i],
        icon: markerIcon,
        labelContent: i.toString(),
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 12),
        labelClass: "my-custom-class-for-label", // the CSS class for the label
        labelInBackground: true
    });
```

I'm updating the position of a *single* marker every 3 seconds. I've also modified the `setContent` function of MarkerWithLabels inside the HTML section. If you open the console, you'll see `setContent` printed along with the content. You'll notice that this happens for all the markers that we've added and not just the marker being updated.

Is this common? Is this how it is supposed to behave?

Comment: How are you defining dynamicMarker?

Comment: @Zelda7 - Added sample Marker creation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in that the `draw` function calls the `setContent` and it looks like `draw` is continuously called.

Not really sure if this should be the case, but a small update (*to store the last used content in the marker and only update it if it has changed*) seems to fix the problem (*without any immediate problems*)

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZogKN

Comment: I'll check this out and see. My gut feeling is that this should not cause any issues. Still not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped ... but I want to be sure since this is a production application. I've posted a query here also - https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/issues/412

Comment: Would be nice to have an official answer, thanks for posting the link here

Comment: Thanks for submitting the merge request. :) I could not find time to get round to it. I think it is apt that you make the contribution as you came up with the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of markers, because seems that the reference it's keeped by useing the same var (it happened to me).

So you can push the markers to an array and get each one by a custom id or by the index.